# Understanding comparisons in Crowcolour by Ted Hughes

Tags: meaning, poetry, ted-hughes

In the poem ["Crowcolour"](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=hz5O0laGLOgC&pg=PT341&lpg=PT341), the shortest of Ted Hughes' Crow poems, there's a series of  comparisons of Crow's blackness with other black images.

Here's the full poem:

> Crow was so much blacker
> Than the moon's shadow
> He had stars.
>
> He was as much blacker
> Than any negro
> As a negro's eye-pupil.
>
> Even, like the sun,
> Blacker
> Than any blindness.

This may be just a plain English question, but still:

Can the middle verse have a different meaning other than the obvious one, by which Crow is:

- **More** black "than any negro"
- **Equally** black "as a negro's eye-pupil"

Such reading is obvious, and hence sounds simplistic to my ears, but maybe it is what is?

P.S.

Not to make this the subject of the question, but if you're wondering what's up with the N-word, see futher reading [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=GVMiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67):

> "Even though the "negro" of "Crowcolour" was a quasi-acceptable term of the period in the US, here it stands in for "African" or even "aboriginal". The analogy between Crow's blackness and the "negro" was for Hughes a positive one, built upon the connection between Crow's primal powers and the of the uncivilized, and thus unfalled, negro.

Also, such usage is also present in Sylvia Plath's poems, such as Ariel, see further reading [here](https://scholarworks.iu.edu/journals/index.php/plath/article/download/4380/4001/13853) (it's a PDF). But see criticism in [this Tweeter thread](https://twitter.com/lutherxhughes/status/1252749299827400705).

Comment: Usually, what is meant by N-word is not *Negro* but *n----r*, which is still a much more offensive term today (and you should realize that *Negro* wasn't offensive at all when Ted Hughes wrote *Crow*).

Comment: And another comment ... I think you have grasped the essential English meaning of the middle verse; I can't think of anything else it could mean. The quote you include (interpreting 'black' as 'aboriginal') is an interesting alternative meaning. But the real question of interpretation for this poem is why Hughes implies the sun as black.